# What are the differences between Ripple and Stellar addresses

Tags: stellar-core, ripple, cryptography

What are the differences between Ripple and Stellar public/private key pairs?

I understand the cryptography and libraries that Ripple and Stellar use are quite similar, but are they practically identical?

Is it possible to derive a Stellar public or private key from a Ripple public or private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stellar uses ed25519 keys, whereas Ripple uses secp256k1 (just as Bitcoin, etc..) by default, and ed25519 if specified.

Ed25519 keys should to be able to be moved between the two systems, with the proper re-encoding.